# pass form instance in django formview

Tags: python, django

I have a `forms.py` file as

```
class SocialMediaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SocialMedia
        fields = "__all__"
        exclude = ("doctor",)
        labels = {}
        widgets = {
            "whatsapp": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "telegram": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "facebook": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "instagram": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "linkedin": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        }
```

with a `view.py` file

```
class SocialMediaProfile(FormView):
    model = DoctorSocialMedia
    form_class = SocialMediaForm
    success_url = "."
    template_name = "doctor/social_media_profile.html"
```

the question is how could i pass a form instance to template in **FormView** view as `SocialMediaForm(instace=someInstance) # in fun based views`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update an instance of a model one should ideally be using [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview):

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView

class SocialMediaProfile(UpdateView):
    model = DoctorSocialMedia
    form_class = SocialMediaForm
    success_url = "."
    template_name = "doctor/social_media_profile.html"
```

This would automatically get the instance from the keyword arguments passed from the urls if they are named as `pk` or `slug`. You can set `slug_url_kwarg` or `pk_url_kwarg` if they are passed with a different name in the url to the view.

If you really need to pass some of your own keyword arguments to the form you should override `get_form_kwargs` (Note: This method would automatically pass the model instance (if exists) if the view inherits from `ModelFormMixin`). Example:

```
class SocialMediaProfile(FormView):
    model = DoctorSocialMedia
    form_class = SocialMediaForm
    success_url = "."
    template_name = "doctor/social_media_profile.html"

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'some_extra_kwarg': 'my_data'})
        return kwargs
```

Comment: thanks for replay sir, there i faced two issues first if the related form doesn't exists it should return an empty form(i don't know) and second that what if user changed the `pk` in **url ** so he/she should not be able to change other models instance.. (don't know possible with which view)

Comment: @AliAref I don't understand what does _"related form doesn't exists"_ mean? Also by _"user changed the pk"_ do you mean the user manually editing the url?

Comment: i mean if there was no `instances` so it should be empty to create one. and yes changing  pk manually from url. (sorry for bad explanations)

Comment: @AliAref please show your model `DoctorSocialMedia` in the question, by any chance is the field `doctor` a one to one field with the user.

Comment: i used **updateview** and passed my parameters to form now working :) Thaaanks so much sir